# 'tileset' is undefined even when an image has been loaded to it

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, sprite

I am making my first game in HTML5 and JavaScript. I am using a Tileset class and a Sprite class. The Tileset class gets the full spritesheet, then in side of ctx.drawImage(), I split the tileset into individual images. When I run it in Chrome and open the console, `undefined` comes up when I try to [access the tileset information](http://pbrd.co/1nu8crf) using. It should come up with `Tileset {image: img, tileWidth: 24, tileHeight: 30}`. All of the pertaining code is included below.

[For a quick and more simple example of what should be happening](http://html5gamedev.samlancashire.com/demos/animation.html)

Tileset class:

```
function Tileset(image, tileWidth, tileHeight) {
    this.image = new Image();
    game.images ++;
    this.image.onload = imageLoaded;
    this.image.src = image;
    this.tileWidth = tileWidth;
    this.tileHeight = tileHeight;
}
```

Sprite class:

```
function Sprite(stateAnimations, startingState, x, y, width, height, speed) {
    this.stateAnimations = stateAnimations;
    this.currentState = startingState;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

Tileset initializer:

```
var playerTiles = new Tileset('playerSpritesheet.png', 24, 30);
```

Sprite initializer:

```
var player = new Sprite({'down': playerDownAnim}, 'down', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 24, 30, 150);
```

Animation for Sprite:

```
var playerDownAnim = new Animation(playerTiles, ['0,0','1,0','2,0'], 150);
```

Finally, the drawSprite() function:

```
function drawSprite(sprite) {
ctx.drawImage(
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.image, 
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].frames[sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].currentFrame].split(',')[0] * sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileWidth,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].frames[sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].currentFrame].split(',')[1] * sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileHeight,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileWidth,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileHeight,
    Math.round(sprite.x),
    Math.round(sprite.y),
    sprite.width,
    sprite.height
);
}
```

Here is my [sprite sheet](http://pbrd.co/1nu7VEw)

Please tell me if I need more code for context or put the code somewhere else like jsFiddle or something.

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: The code that you show seems correct, so the glitch has to happen somewhere else. 1) You should factorize every time you can, one example, in drawSprite : use ‘var anims=sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState];‘, then you can make your code more readable. 2) Yes, build a basic jsfiddle, that will help us help you.

Comment: GameAlchemist: Thank you for your comment. I have already found the error. It was really stupid. The functions and variables were initailized out of order.